# Random function in Racket (even more complex)

Tags: function, random, racket

I want to make an even more complex random function in Racket.

The function will have two input list as parameters (assuming the lists will have the same length):

- One will be for the elements it can return
- The other will be for the probability. Let my make it clear, if the list is ‘(1 1 2) the probability to get the first element will be the same than the second element, but the 3rd element’s probability will be double than the first and the second. If the list is ‘(1 2 4) the probability of the second element will be the double of the first element but the half of the 3rd element.

So if we have as the inputs arguments ‘(e t k) and ‘(1 2 3). The probability of getting a “t” will be the double of an “e”. And the probability of getting a “k” will be the triple of an “e”.

If we have as the inputs arguments ‘(k u y t) and ‘(1 1 2 1). The probability of getting a “y” will be the double of a “k”, “u” and “t”. And the probability of getting a “k”, “u” and “t” will be the same between them.

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be homework and the poster has not shown what has already been tried, or how far he/she got.

Comment: @JohnClements My usual remedy to such questions is to answer the way a seasoned Schemer would answer, using any SRFIs or modules that we would normally solve it with. The OP would then be forced to actually adapt the code to whatever restricted subset of the language their professor requires them to use. I'm okay with that, as long as they're actually doing _that_ work rather than offloading it to someone else.

Comment: @John Clements Thank you for the answers. Im trying hard to learn Schemer.I know C(not an expert)but it is being really hard for me to learn Schemer fast.I have many document/books that I am reading as for example:1)“The Littler Schemer” 2)”Revised report on the algorithmic Language Scheme” 3)”Teach Yourself Scheme in Fixnum days”.But I can’t get enough knowledge just reading and I need some examples to “play” with and learn it through iteration.In that sense “The Littler Schemer” seems good for the basics, but now I am looking something more complex in order to improve. [Continues]

Comment: @Chirs Jester-Young. [Continues the previous comment] The idea is learn about list processing, random generation of list, swaping list properties, adding one row to a list, read list from files, creating rows following some indications…
And all of this to manage later Learning Algorithms.
So, I will really appreciate if you recommend me any web or book were I can learn about Schemer oriented to these objetives.
Thank you very much. John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the frequencies are all integers:

```
(define (random-item lst)
  (list-ref lst (random (length lst))))

(define (random-item/frequencies lst freqs)
  (random-item (append-map make-list freqs lst)))
```

If the frequencies involve non-integral quantities, things are a little trickier:

```
(define (random-item/frequencies lst freqs)
  ; rcfs = reversed cumulative frequencies
  (define rcfs (foldl (lambda (e r) (cons (+ e (car r)) r)) '(0) freqs))
  (define threshold (* (random) (car rcfs)))
  (for/first ([item (in-list lst)]
              [cf (in-list (cdr (reverse rcfs)))]
              #:when (> cf threshold))
    item))
```